# jQuery how to get data-value where class active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get data-value where the class is active. when I am clicking on nav-tabs it alerting undefined How can I resolve this error? Please help me.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active" data-value="buy"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">BUY</a></li>
  <li data-value="rent"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">RENT</a></li>
  <li><a href="Post_Property.html">SALE</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
  $(".nav-tabs").click(function(){
    alert($(".active").attr("data-value"));
  })
```

Comment: probably some other element in page that has that class and it is higher in the dom than the one you want.

Comment: Don't see any issue with your code. It should work. Are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: The problem is here class active changing after an alert so I want to get cursor clicked on which LI?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap.js for tabs? If so use bootstrap tabs events api from docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.nav-tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      alert($(".active").attr("data-value"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active" data-value="buy"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">BUY</a></li>
  <li data-value="rent"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">RENT</a></li>
  <li><a href="Post_Property.html">SALE</a></li>
</ul>
```

I had updated the changes in the code u can use shown.bs.tab method for bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data attribute like:

```
$(".active").data("value");
```

it will return the `data-value` and in your case the DOM is not properly traversed. The proper code is:

```
$(".nav-tabs").click(function(){
    alert($(this).find(".active").data("value"));
})
```

as `.active` is the child of `.nav-tabs`, so you have to traverse it.

Comment: The problem is here class active changing after an alert so I want to get cursor clicked on which LI?

Answer (score 0):

Simply traverse and get the active tag, like this:

```
$(".nav-tabs").click(function(){
    alert($(this).find(".active").attr("data-value"));
});
```

Also, instead of `attr('data-value')`, you can use `data("value")`.

Comment: The problem is here class active changing after an alert so I want to get cursor clicked on which LI?]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit and explain what do you mean by "active changing"?